# Reading a CSV file with differing number of instances of a particular separator into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file, which uses semicolon `(;)` as a separator. However, the thing is that the number of instances of semicolon differ, that is sometimes there is only a single `;`, sometimes multiple semicolons like `;;;;`, `;;;;;;` etc., which I don't really know considering the fact that the data is fairly large.

The simplest way (and obviously the common way) to read the file with a `;` separator is to use

```
data = pd.read_csv('my_file_name.csv', sep = ';')
```

However, the problem is that although the file is read into the pandas data frame `data`, there are incorrect instances of reading the file's columns, as the number of separators vary (though it is sure that the delimiter/separator would be a semicolon, but the number of them is something which varies widely like `;`, `;;;`, `;;;;` etc.

What I would like to accomplish is to be able to read the CSV file properly into a Pandas data frame, and considering `;` as the delimiter/separator. When there is at least one `;`, it can be considered as the delimiter. The problem arises, that I don't know whether to specify `;` as separator, `;;;` as separator etc., because the number of instances of semicolon across the dataset varies, which I am not sure of (thus making it unfeasible to use `or |` operator)

I tried to use `sep = None` and set the `engine = 'python`, but it isn't working in reading the CSV file correctly into the data frame.

```
data = pd.read_csv('my_file_name.csv', sep = None, engine = 'python')
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How working `sep="[;]+", engine='python'` ?

Comment: Did you try the above? Also, is it possible that the two or three semi-colons in a row actually means blank fields?

Comment: @jezrael I tried this but still the file doesn't seem to be read correctly. There are some columns which are completely having NaNs, which is surely not the case with the actual data. But, the problem is that ; is varying in number of times it occurs. But, definitely, the separator will either be a single ;, or a group of semicolons.

Comment: @scharfmn I tried the above which unfortunately didn't work for me. No, multiple semicolons don't mean that these are blank fields. Its only a way in which the data has been arranged (sometimes they have used a single ; and sometimes a group of semicolons. But definitely, it is not the case that there are columns with all NaNs, as is happening while reading the data into the data frame presently.

Comment: Ok, this may be a bad idea, but did you try: save a copy; open up the copy with a text editor; do a regex search and replace to trim the multiples down to a single; save; try to read into pandas? Could also script that etc.

Comment: (Note that this would almost certainly corrupt your data in some way, but at least you could get an idea of what's in it etc)

Answer (score -1):

Dataset is normally available as ' **;** ' separated field as below
[image]

In above show the student dataset and we can separate it only from ' **;** '. We cannot use sep = None.

Here is some example python code use in student dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv" ,sep=";")
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. What is the purpose of using machine learning in here? My question was about reading a CSV file as a Pandas Dataframe with differing number of separator instances.

Comment: I answer that as we can separate using ; from csv. Please check your csv file is it separeted from ; or not

Comment: It is possible to use separator as None. Refer http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html  and the answer by @Anaidel on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359598/load-csv-with-unknown-delimiter-into-pandas-dataframe. But anyways, you just mention how to read a CSV file which I already know pretty well (its the same thing I mentioned in the question). Can you add something substantial to your answer, which would be helpful to others on SO? Again, sklearn has nothing to do in this case.